# Don't understand return type

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec calcTotalMonths ~moneyOwed:moneyOwed ~interestRate:interestRate ~monthlyPayment:monthlyPayment ~months:months=0 = (   
  let newBalance = (moneyOwed -. monthlyPayment) *. interestRate in   
  match newBalance <= 0. with 
    true -> months 
  | false -> calcTotalMonths newBalance interestRate monthlyPayment months+1
);;
```

I was wondering why I keep getting

```
File "budget.ml", line 19, characters 12-73:
Error: This expression has type
         moneyOwed:float ->
         interestRate:float -> monthlyPayment:float -> months:'a -> 'b
```

Why is months a type 'a when it clearly uses the '+' operator on months. It also returns months at the base case of recursion so why is it a 'b as the return type.

EDIT: 
after doing Jeff's suggestion

```
File "budget.ml", line 19, characters 12-77:
Error: This expression has type
         moneyOwed:float ->
         interestRate:float -> monthlyPayment:float -> months:int -> 'a
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the optional argument to the front and use labels at the call site:

```
let rec calcTotalMonths ?(months=0) ~moneyOwed ~interestRate ~monthlyPayment =
  let newBalance = (moneyOwed -. monthlyPayment) *. interestRate in
  if newBalance <= 0.0 then
    months
  else
    calcTotalMonths
      ~months:(months + 1)
      ~moneyOwed:newBalance
      ~interestRate
      ~monthlyPayment
```

Note that this uses some shorthand for labelled arguments: `~argname:argname` can be replaced with just `~argname`. Moving optional arguments away from the last position is done to avoid an unfortunate facet of the labelled arguments system: see [the manual's description of optional arguments](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/lablexamples.html#sec43) for the details.

Looking at this, I sense the possibility that you only intend to use the `months` argument from within `calcTotalMonths`, and that the optionality of the argument exists to hide it from external callers. If so, this is not good style. A better approach would be a nested function to handle the loop:

```
let calcTotalMonths ~moneyOwed ~interestRate ~monthlyPayment =
  let rec loop months balance =
    let newBalance = (balance -. monthlyPayment) *. interestRate in
    if newBalance <= 0.0 then months
    else loop (months + 1) newBalance in
  loop 0 moneyOwed
```

(Ignore that if you really need the argument.)

Answer (score 3):

You're not applying `+` to months, you're applying it to the result of `calcTotalMonths`.  Function application has higher precedence than infix operators.

The expression is interpreted as if you wrote this:

```
(calcTotalMonths newBalance interestRate monthlyPayment months) + 1
```

You should write this:

```
calcTotalMonths newBalance interestRate monthlyPayment (months + 1)
```

**Update**

It looks like you want `months` to be an optional parameter with a default value of 0. The way to define that is like this:

```
? (months = 0)
```

Note: it's not good form to have trailing optional arguments, as it leads to problems with partially applying your function.

**Update 2**

Finally, if you want to call a function that has labelled arguments, but without supplying the labels, you can only supply the *non-optional* parameters. This doesn't work for you, because you need to supply the months in your recursive calls. I think things will work if you supply all the labels in your recursive call.

**Update 3**

For what it's worth (a moderate amount), here's how I would write this function. I don't use labelled or optional arguments except when they're solving a serious problem. Also, I think a helper function is a much better way to handle the iteration count (months):

```
let monthsUntilPaid owed interest payment =
    let rec go balance months =
         let balance' = (balance -. payment) *. interest in
         if balance' <= 0.0 then months else go balance' (months + 1)
    in
    go owed 0
```

(I just noticed that gsg also showed how to use a helper function.)

Comment: so this fixes the type problem on months, but what about the entire return type of the function?